# Hadoop mapreduce against Cassandra, memory leak

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I am running a simple mapreduce program on Hadoop cluster against Cassandra.
I am reading and posting back the data from and to Cassandra.

I tried to run the example from Github (against some real data) and in the *reduce* phase, I get this error:

> ERROR util.ResourceLeakDetector: LEAK: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances.  HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the JVM,so that only a few instances are created.

How can I get rid of that? 
I am not instantiating any Cluster resource, I am using the *datastax* Java libraries.

[Example from Github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count/src/WordCount.java)